# ToDo backbone LocalStorage is file://

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

I have a backbone todo app running locally and I am trying to delete some entries. The "X" 's don't work. And if I delete the local storage through Chrome Dev Tools , they still reappear after I reload. It says `"file://"` in the list with a Hash as the value, but I cant find a file. It shouldn't work after I delete the reference anyway.Whats going on here that I cant figure out?
Mike

Comment: do you run the app by a server? Or do you simply open the html file from the filesystem?

Comment: I am testing with File System , not a WebServer.

Comment: I think you shold provide code. Is there some error message in the console? What is the datasource? Is it a JSON file? You cannot delete datasets from files